# Property 'msg' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(7053)

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because the expression of type '"msg"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
Property 'msg' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(7053)**

*Ts .*

```js
export class ViewdataComponent implements OnInit {
  
 private freshdata: RegisData[];
 
  constructor(public mydata:RegServiceService) { }
 
  ngOnInit()  {
    this.refreshData();
    
  }
  refreshData(){
    this.mydata.readData().subscribe(
     data=>{ 
      console.log(data); 
         this.freshdata=data['msg'];
         console.log(this.freshdata);
     },
     error=>{
       console.log(error);
     }
    )
  }
}
```

`console.log(data)` prints out:

```json
{
   "msg":[{
      "_id":"60cec931210d5d0d40f43291",
      "name":"fghbdf",
      "dob":"dfg",
      "phno":"dfgsd",
      "addr":"dfg",
      "__v":0
   }]
}
```

I need to save the data inside msg as a variable name of `this.freshdata`
so write it like this

```js
this.freshdata=data['msg'];
console.log(this.freshdata);
```

but `data['msg']` give an error:

> msg does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: as msg is an array try accessing it like `data['msg'][0]`

Comment: this.freshdata = data.msg
try this way